# Indefinite articles and ordinals

Tags: articles

I was told that when ordinals are used (e.g., first, second, third), the noun they modify should use the definite article "the" (e.g., "the second phenomenon", "the first study on physics"). Are there cases where the indefinite articles (a/an) are acceptable (e.g., "a third phenomenon", "a first study on physics")?

Comment: "I was told that ... the noun they modify should use the definite article *the*" -- That was **wrong.** Both kind of articles may be used. The context decides which is appropriate.

Comment: This question is based on a misconception.

Answer (score 1):

Examples

#### Many candidates for a singular role

- Mahjong requires four players. We only have three players at the table. Hey you (yelling to a room of other people watching football on TV), we need a fourth player!!

#### Multiple instances, where each instance has a singular role

- Mary is the 2nd in command in the team. Matt is the 2nd in command in his team. Amanda too is a 2nd in command. This is a team of 2nd-in-commands. Hey you (yelling to a bystanding conference participant), are you a 2nd-in-command too. If you are, come and join us.
- I believe everyone who gets a disheartening diagnostic from a doctor, should get a second opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the examples, @Blessed Geek. Honestly, I never thought of these instances.

Comment: I have no idea why someone would bother to down-vote my examples. I have a feeling someone has been vindictively trolling me for a previous discussion he/she did not agree with.